# use variable in str_detect's first argument

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyeval

I want to use the `str_detect`function passing a variable as the first argument. Meaning this could theoretically look something like this.

```
# create the variable
var = names(mtcars)[1]
mtcars %>% 
  mutate(
    new_var = case_when(str_detect(var, "^2"), "two", "other")
  )
```

Now I'm not sure how to insert the variable `var` correctly into the `str_detect` function. I guess some tidy-eval is necessary, but I'm not sure....

Comment: Is this inside a function you are writing? If so, that makes a difference. Could you put this in a broader context? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using mtcars as an exmaple for string manipulation is not very helpful, so switching over to `iris`.  Also, your `case_when` specification was wrong, so I'm using `if_else` for this example.

You can use `!!(sym(var))`

```
library(tidyverse)
var <- "Species"
iris %>% 
  mutate(
    new_var = if_else(str_detect(!!sym(var), "set"), "two", "other")
  )

  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species new_var
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa     two
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa     two
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa     two
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa     two
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa     two
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa     two
```

Comment: I recommend using the `.data` pronoun: `str_detect(.data[[var]])`. See https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/topic-data-mask-programming.html#names-patterns